# Create page from post attachments

Tags: attachments

WordPress provides attachment pages out of the box. But is it somehow possible to have page with listing of all attachments that are connected to a certain post? It should basically work as a gallery overview. So this is not to be on the post page, but on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. I think, you should do that with `page-template`.
For that, create a page template. Easiest way is:

1) Inside your theme folder, make a duplicate of `page.php` and name it i.e. `my-page.php`

2) open that file and in the top, after `<?php` place this:

```
/**
* Template Name: my templt for attchmnts
*/
```

3) then just remove the content `<div>` (you should determine that area) and place this code:

```
<?php
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'parent'    =>  $_GET['post_id'],
) );

foreach ( $attachments as $each ) {
    echo 'Title is:' . $each->post_title . ' [content is]: ' . $each->post_content ."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

(This is just a skeleton, you should build other things yourself.)

then open a new page (i.e. `exmaple.com/my_pageee`) and choose that template while publishing the page (under PUBLISH button). Then you should access that page like this:

```
example.com/my_pageee?post_id=436
```

so, you will get all attachments for post `436`

Comment: that's cool Tazo!  Can you do it with CPT fields too?